# Mathematica function defining problem

Tags: function-construction

[image]

The "F" function is defined as mentioned, but when I call the function F inside the code, "F" can't compute value using the function F, just give F_0, F_1, etc. Can somebody guide me what is the problem with the definition?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. In order to replicate the difficulty you face in our own notebooks so that it can be studied and resolved promptly, we need you to provide copy-paste-able Mathematica code. Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: Something like `f[k_+1]:=k^2` will not work, you would have to rewrite that as `f[k_]:=(k-1)^2`.

Comment: Pattern matching is literal. `Subscript[F, 0]` does not match the pattern `Subscript[F, Plus[1, Pattern[k, Blank[]]]]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code with correct syntax:

```
z[0] = 1;
z[k_] := (1 - (1 + a)/k) z[k - 1];
f[k_] := (3/2)^
    a (Sum[z[k] z[k - t + 1], {r, 2, k}] + (1/2^(k + 1) z[k + 1]));
m0 = 1/(25 f[0]/36 + 10  s1/3)
m1 = -5 f[0]/72 + 2 s1/3 
m2 = -f[0]/144 + s1/6
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much